# How to add childrens to a UserControl?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, grid, controls, containers

I created my own Usercontrol, a simply Grid with a background color and a title label. That works, i can add this Usercontrol in my project.

But now i want to be able to add childrens to this Usercontrol. So I created a grid in the Usercontrol and in this grid i want to add the childrens. So basically when i say:

```
    MyUserControl.childrens.add(New Label())
```

Of course i can make a method in my UserControl and then simply add this object to the grid, like this:

```
    Public Sub addChild(byval o as object)
      gridForChildrens.Childrens.add(o)
    End Sub
```

But the problem is: I want to be able to drag and drop controls in the designer and in the xaml into the Usercontrol and this doesnt work. So when i do this the background color and the header label simply disappear.

Thanks for your Help!

Here is my xaml problem:

```
<UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
        <Border BorderBrush="#9B000000" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0">
            <Grid Margin="0" Name="outerGrid" Background="AliceBlue">

                <Label x:Name="Hallo" Content="someText"/>
                <!-- Content -->
                <ContentPresenter Name="MainContent" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>
```

So i cant access the "Hallo" Label in my code now for some reason...

Comment: if drag&droped controls replace userControl content it may be an issue with userControl (not designer), which uses default `Content` instead of default `Template`. similar case here: [content-overriding-entire-user-control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717035/content-overriding-entire-user-control-rather-than-contentpresenter). can you also add control xaml markup to your question, please?

Comment: Yes thats my problem. When i create a contentPresenter then it works. But in this case i cant access to this objects in the Content presentor.